# Directing wsgi to the correct python

Tags: wsgi

I'm trying to run a django app with wsgi on apache on acentos6.5.
Centos6.5 comes with python2.6 while I need python2.7 so I've installed it and want to use my virtualenv.
Since apache was complaining that it does not find django, I decided to set the python home but then it complains that it cannot even the os package.
Here is my httpd.conf:

```
WSGIPythonHome /root/venv/bin
WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName    myproj.com
  Serveralias www.   myproj.com
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www/   myproj
  ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/   myproj_error.log
  CustomLog /var/log/httpd/   myproj_access.log combined
  WSGIDaemonProcess    myproj python-path=/var/www/   myproj:/root/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/root/venv/lib/python2.7:/root/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
  WSGIProcessGroup    myproj
  WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/   myproj/   myproj/wsgi.py
  <Directory /var/www/   myproj/>
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from all
  </Directory>

  <Directory /root/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/>
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

here is the path of my virtualenv:

```
/root/venv/bin/python2.7
```

Can someone guide me how to make wsgi find and use my python2.7?
Note: I easily made it work on ubuntu so there must be a trick to centos.
Note: I'm sure that it's using python2.6 because I put a log statement in wsgi.py.

Comment: Are you using the centos mod_wsgi package? mod_wsgi will only work with an instance of the same major/minor version of python that it was compiled against. See https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIPythonHome

Comment: yes. I did yum install libapache2-mod-wsgi. I guess it must have used the system python.